Help finding the title of a kid's book about an overconfident man swapping bodies with a devil
It's a children's book I read in elementary school. I don't remember much and I could be misremembering what I do remember.
Basically it was about a man who is very strong and never loses a fight. I remember one part where he fights a bull (or possibly a similar animal like an Ox) with his bare hands and wins. Becoming arrogant and overconfident he climbs to the top of a mountain and shouts a declaration to the world asking if there is anyone who can challenge him. He then hears a voice shout back to him saying "Skin for Skin". I don't remember much after that but if I recall correctly he keeps hearing the same voice following him everywhere he goes repeating the words "Skin for Skin". I remember it then ends with him loosing a challenge that he didn't realize he was in and ends up swapping bodies with the devil or a devil like creature.
I remember that it was illustrated and has a picture of him and the devil riding on the back of a bull through the night sky. At least I believe it was a bull and it was flying.
I don't remember when it was written but it would have been no later than 2001.

I wonder if this is a variant of the story of Strap Buckner.
I am not familiar with the story, but I remembered a reference to it in Manly Wade Wellman's story Walk Like a Mountain:

I allowed he minded me of Strap Buckner with that talk.
"Who's Strap Buckner? Why do I mind you of him?"
I picked the guitar, I sang the song:
Strap Buckner he was called, he was more than eight foot tall,
And he walked like a mountain among men.
He was good and he was great, and the glorious Lone Star State
Will never look upon his like again.
"Strap Buckner had the strength of ten lions," I said, "and he used it as ten lions. Scorned to fight ordinary folks, so he challenged old Satan himself, skin for skin, on the banks of the Brazos, and if Satan hadn't fought foul ...

There's a version of the story by Connie Nordhielm Wooldridge published about the time you remember reading it.

I found a version of the story in the Legends of Texas anthology on Project Gutenberg. If you search for skin for skin you'll find the Strap Buckner story about halfway down:

“‘Skin for skin,’ said the figure. At the same time he twirled his tail
over again with such force and accurate aim that the sharp point of it
stuck deeply into the mantel-piece, and there it hung fixed.
“‘What might thy name be,’ said Strap, ‘who visitest me at this
unseemly hour? Speak! thy name and thy business!’
“‘Sir,’ said the object, rising from the chair, extracting its tail
from the mantel-piece, and advancing a step toward Strap, ‘men call me
by many names. Thou hast called me “black imp of hell, thou Satanas!”
So be it. Skin for skin! Thou hast thrice challenged me to duel, and
thrice have I accepted. I have come to meet thee now, or to fling thy
challenge into thy teeth.’

